# Javascript array mutation in looping with a callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I implement looping with a callback using `call()` function (example from http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#28, see below)

```
function loop(array, fn){ 
  for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) 
    fn.call( array, array[i], i ); 
}
```

To modify contents of the array, I can use

```
var a = [0,1,2]
loop(a, function(v, i) { this[i] = 0; }); // a = [0,0,0]
```

but not

```
var a = [0,1,2]
loop(a, function(v, i) { v = 0; }); // a = [0,1,2]
```

Why does that happen? `this` is `array`, so `this[i]` and `array[i]` and `v` are the same. However, in one case the array is modified, in another it stays immutable.

Comment: Because reassigning a variable in javascript will not update whatever that variable was referencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `fn.call( array, array[i], i );` is invoked then within `fn()`:

- `this` stores a reference to `array`;
- `v` is a variable storing the value of `array[i]` (and can be thought of as doing `var v = array[i];` at the start of the function's scope); and
- `i` is a variable storing the value of the current index of the array.

Note that `this` stores a reference whereas `v` and `i` are variables storing values.

In the first function (`loop(a, function(v, i) { this[i] = 0; });`) is the equivalent, for each array element, of `var v = a[i]; a[i] = 0;` (since `this` within the function is `a`) and so the array is updated as the value `0` is assigned to the given index of the array.

However, in the second function (`loop(a, function(v, i) { v = 0; });`) is the equivalent, for each array element, of `var v = a[i]; v = 0;` and so the array is not updated as the value '0' is assigned to a variable `v` within the function's scope and not to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Because reassigning a variable in javascript will not update whatever that variable was referencing. In the first snippet you are reassigning the index `i` of an array to the new value `0`. In the second snippet you are just reassigning the `v` to 0 which will not modify the array.

Essentially what you're doing to simply is

```
var a = [1,2,3];
//first case
var v = a[1];
a[1] = 0;
//Array value of index 1 is updated

//second case
var v = a[1];
v = 2;
//array value of index 1 is not updated
```